# How to create end user login page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

[image]I am new to WordPress. Help me create end user login page. I have created and site with a theme. My requirement is to create a login page for the site not for the dashboard.

Only if they login, they should be able to access other pages
I need lo add an sign in page for the site, and then user should visit be able to visit these pages

Comment: This is too broad, please show your efforts, what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have takem an theme and created pages like home about us etc, now I want to create login page for the entire site like flipkart amazon etc.I think I am clear with my requirement

Comment: do you know how to modify or write php?

Comment: yes, but if I write any code will it affect wordpress anyway..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking to have login form on front end then there are multiple plugins available out there. Checkout **UserPro** plugin.

Also Free plugin like **'Theme My Login (TML)'** can be used to provide login functionality on front end. These are just examples, there are many others as well. 
Let me know if this helps or feel free to discuss more in details.

Comment: Knew about it already and tried,this gives login to the dashboard not to the front end. I want the login to control access over my site not to the adin dashboard

Comment: If you want that no user other than admin can access wp-admin dashboard then you can try out some hooks or [plugin like this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-dashboard-access-for-non-admins/)

Comment: After putting login form, here is hook to disable users to access backend
`add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );

function blockusers_init() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && 
       ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}` @Karthikeyansundaramoorthi

Answer (score 3):

**This is very well possible.** You can even do this without any advanced coding skills, but it requires some (very popular) plugins.

Use the 'sidebar login widget' to let people login on any part of your website and use 'login redirect' to send them to a specific private(!) page, based on their role.

I can recommend the 'TML plugin', Faisal suggests, to make the experience even more polished. Additionally you can use the 'User role editor' to customize your roles and/or create new ones.

- Sidebar login: https://wordpress.org/plugins/sidebar-login/
- Login redirect:
  https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/screenshots/
- TML plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/
- User role editor: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

Answer (score 0):

Its Very Simple Just Search for Login box in Plugin > add New and Install the plugin.
after put the code where you want to show the login box. 
you will find the code in plugin setting.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to quickly mod any theme is to get  membership plugin or users add-on plugin. They usually have the basic stuff like login register customisation and my accaunt page. 
Try https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-ultra/ but in your case maybe it will be an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

you can also modify your plugin file name form-login.php in wp-conttent/plugin/templates

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Theme My Login, ProfilePress is another great option. They even have an article on creating a [custom login page](https://profilepress.com/article/create-custom-wordpress-login-page/). And it's a completely free plugin available [in the WordPress plugin repo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/).

Answer (score -2):

Since wordpress is an blogging framework we can use it for blogging purpose efficiently.. For building custom sites with javascript functionalities you have to edit **index.php**  and **header.php** under your theme and then add your custom code.

*To be short wordpress does not provide any end user login for site by default, **only some of the paid theme supports** that*

Comment: First of all, editing the header.php to inject javascript is not the proper way, see this beginners manual: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/. Secondly, WordPress does provide this functionality by default and it is called private pages.

Comment: PS. In my opinion WordPress is not very well categorized as an efficient blogging framework. It is/has become too bloated (and private pages is a good example). For efficient blogging you can best try a light (and secure) tool, like Jekyll.